# Stripped Down CKEditor Vs Markdown

Tags: wysiwyg, markdown

I have been looking into why WYSIWYG editors are bad for content creation. The most common reason given is that they output incorrect html. But what if I use editors with reduced functionality?

My requirements are only the ability to italicize, make text bold, create ordered/unordered lists and (maybe at a later date) add inline images.
My users will hopefully be 'persistent' users (small numbers of laypersons using the app frequently)

In this context how do I choose between Markdown (WMD editor) & a stripped down WYSIWYG editor. How would page performance be affected with each? I consider fidelity & reproduciblity of data to be important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You choose by considering your audience. Wiki markup and markdown is for geeks. Your customers sound like they're probably not geeks so I would suggest CKEditor or Twiki-style editor (good, simple Wysiwyg UI) for non-geek users.

Basic concern: Why force lay-people to learn a markup language when solid alternatives exist?

See the Custom Toolbar editor in [this CKEditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo). Or check out [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is reassuring. All day long I have been reading why Markdown/Textile are better than WYSIWYG. Been slightly scared.

Comment: Yes, people tend to go far to one side or the other when they blog and otherwise discuss online, it's human nature. E.g. your question. The pragmatic answer usually lies somewhere in the middle. (Oops, almost said always.) In any case, there's nothing more reassuring (or horrifying) than taking a piece of software for a test drive.

Answer (score 9):

OK, I tested both.
Even for my basic formatting requirements, CKEditor generated quite ghastly html

Now this is the input

```
This actually appears to be better  
I hope users understand what we are doing  
Lets see

But in the meantime
```

CKEditor Output

```
<p> This actually appears to be better</p>
<p> I hope users understand what we are doing</p>
<p> Lets see</p>
<p> &nbsp;</p>
<p> But in the meantime</p>
```

And Markdown Output

```
<p>This actually appears to be better <br>
I hope users understand what we are doing <br>
Lets see</p>

<p>But in the meantime</p>
```

Now if this is the difference between these two for the most basic formatting (linebreaks and paragraphs), what will it be like in a 200 word submission. I think most users will need to know only this

```
For line breaks, two SPACES and hit ENTER.
For new paragraphs, hit ENTER twice
```

The rest of the stuff could be learnt incrementally
Is it that hard to engineer a 'basic' WYSIWYG editor?

**EDIT**

After adding these to config.js above problem is solved

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

Comment: Your users don't care about the internal code (as long as they are normal users), so they don't care if an enter generates a P or BR, they just want the editor work as much as possible as MS-Word. If you think that your users will be happy learning Markdown or another syntax go ahead, but in any other case, think about setting p {margin:0} in your stylesheet and using a WYSIWYG editor with the features that you want.

Comment: The CKEditor is highly configurable; I was able to tune it to my requirements. Markdown is simple - but even I wasn't able to figure out how to create lists, so I wont be subjecting lay users to it. Thanks

Comment: +1 but... lol. You think CKEditor produces ghastly HTML? Try creating a page in M$ Word and then exporting it to HTML. Warning: You might need a lead apron and nuke-blast shades! You haven't seen ugly until you've seen that!

Comment: I would like to retract 'ghastly' in my answer, but wouldn't it be against SO conventions :-)